# Sharepoint 2016, insert version number in word document

Tags: azure, ms-word, versioning, sharepoint-2016

I'm trying to find a way to automatically add version number to a word document that is created in sharepoint 2016. We had the label solution before but now that is deprecated and i really can't find anything on the internet on how to fix the issue.

We had this solution before

[How can I include value of sharepoint's version column in a word document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508229/how-can-i-include-value-of-sharepoints-version-column-in-a-word-document)

But that is depricated in 2016.

Anyone got any other simple solution?

Was wondering of fixing a webhook and using it togheter with azure functions. But for such a small thing it seems so unecessary.

Comment: I am looking at how do this as well